# How can I solve this second order differential equation using series?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Here's the question

Solve in series
$\;\;x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2y=0$

when i brought the above equation to the form $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+P(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+Q(x)y=0$, I get $P(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $Q(x)=x$. This means that $P(x)$ is not analytic at $x=0$ but $Q(x)$ is analytic at $x=0.$ How do i now proceed ? Please help

Comment: The problem states "Solve in series ...". So, you are supposed to assume a power series $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$.

Furthermore, there is no need to divide by $x$. Just leave the equation as it is and plug in the power series.

Comment: Yes, but the series $y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is to be used when both $P(x)\; and\; Q(x)$ are analytic. Here $P(x)$ is not

Comment: This is what my book says...

Comment: And I say, do not divide by $x$ and all stays analytic and you can plug in the power series :-).

Comment: @AkshajJumde I agree with trancelocation's comments. I did a quick check myself and it's working properly to determine the various coefficients, apart from one parameter, with this likely to be determined based on some sort of initial or boundary condition.

Comment: Okay.. let me try by this approach. Thanks for the help everybody

Comment: You have a regular singularity at $x=0$ if $xP(x)$ and $x^2Q(x)$ are continuous in $x=0$, which is the case here. Failing that, there is no guarantee that a power series solution exists.